# TypeError object is not iterable in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a movie site using Django. I have created a Genre model in it and displayed it in the template. Now i want those each genre objects to redirect to some other page. For example i have created 45 genre types and displayed in the template. Now what i want to do is, redirect user to for example Action genre list when clicked on Genre Action in the template. For that i used for loop in template but when clicked in any of the genre objects it throws
TypeError at /home/genre/5/
'Genre' object is not iterable. What is the problem here? Any suggestions will be great.

my urls.py:

`urlapatterns = [path('', views.home, name='home'), path('genre/<int:pk>, views.genreView, name='home')]`

views.py:

```
def genreView(request, pk):
genres = get_object_or_404(Genre, id=pk)
context = {
    'genres': genres
}

return render(request, 'genre.html', context)

def home(request):
genres = Genre.objects.all()
context = {
    'genres': genres
}

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

home.html:

```
{% for genre in genres %}
  <a href="{% url 'genre' genre.id %}" class="text-yellow-400 hover:text-white p-2 text-xs">{{genre.title}}</a>     
{% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
 class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, `genres` is not a `QuerySet` (collection) of `Genres`, but a single `Genre` object, you thus should simply render the details of that genre:

```
def genreView(request, pk):
    genre = get_object_or_404(Genre, id=pk)
    context = {
        'genre': genre
    }
    return render(request, 'genre.html', context)
```

and in your `genre.html` you should *not* iterate over the `genre`, but render this like:

```
<!-- genre.html -->
<!-- do not iterate over genre -->

{{ genre.title }}
<!-- … -->
```

Comment: rendering the genre objects is fine but the problem arise when i want to redirect to the detail page of one of the particular genre..the rendering works fine . for example when i want to redirect to Action genre page using dynamic url it says 'Genre' object is not iterable. if i was to create a page for each genre i would have to create 50+ pages. to avoid this i used for loop which is necessary for my case

Comment: @AmitBuyo: the `name=...` of your view is `'home'` in your `urls.py`, so to refer to that, you need `{% url 'home' genre.pk %}`.